# SwiftSpinner having issue while calling API - swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, spinner, swift4

Im facing an issue with the SwiftSpinner which I download from here https://github.com/icanzilb/SwiftSpinner

Im trying to show spinner everytime app push an api call. Then hide the spinner after request completed. The problem is while spinner's initialing the request had completed and call the hiding event. Finally, the spinner completed its initial process and display. And of course, because request had completed then no thing can hide it. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 static func request(target: ServerAPI, success successCallback: @escaping (Response) -> Void, error errorCallback: @escaping (Swift.Error) -> Void, failure failureCallback: @escaping (MoyaError) -> Void) {

    // Show spinner
    SwiftSpinner.show()

    print("Start: \(target.path)")
    provider.request(target) { (result) in
        // Hide spinner
        SwiftSpinner.hide()


        switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            // do my stuff 
        default
            // do my stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The UIChanges must be done on Main Thread.
When you wants to hide spinner get main thread and the hide it.

Use following

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async{
  SwiftSpinner.hide()

  }
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me. I have a tabbarcontroller. When I tap to one of tabbar icons. It calls api and cannot hide the spinner. Any idea? thanks

Comment: You need to provide detailed info about your code otherwise no one can help you. For example where do you call that api call in your viewDidLoad or somewhere else ?